# Prove the following by deduction rules for qualifiers and implication

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am having trouble with the following proof. First, some basic definitions:

1. Def. Given two statements $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the statement \begin{equation}\alpha \implies \beta ,\end{equation} read as "$\alpha \ \mathrm{implies} \ \beta $ ", means \begin{equation}``\alpha \  \mathrm{implies} \ \beta " \end{equation} which is the same as to say \begin{equation}``\mathrm{if} \ \alpha \ \mathrm{then} \ \beta" .\end{equation}
2. Axm (Deduction Rules for Implication). From $\alpha$ and $\alpha \implies \beta$ we can conclude $\beta$. The statement $\alpha \implies \beta$ can be concluded after $\beta$ was concluded from $\alpha$.

We have to follow a very specific structure in our proofs. This is what's confusing me. We are supposed to give the proof in a nested manner where an inner block is proved first.

Prove the following, where variables represent
natural numbers (including the number $0$):
\begin{equation}
\quad \forall_{x}\left[\left[ \forall_{y}\left[x+y=1+y\right]\right]\implies\left[\exists_{z}\left[x+z=2\right]\right]\right]
\end{equation}
My (updated) attempt:

\begin{align}
    1&. \quad \forall_{x}\left[\left[ \forall_{y}\left[x+y=1+y\right]\right]\implies\left[\exists_{z}\left[x+z=2\right]\right]\right]   \\
    2&. \quad x &(declare)\\
    3&. \quad \forall_{y} \left[ x+y=1+y  \right] &(assumed)\\
    4&. \quad y=1 &(UI) \\
    5&. \quad x + 1 = 1 + 1 &(4,3)\\
    6&. \quad x + 1 = 2 &(5, Peano Ax.)\\
    7&. \quad z=1 &(choose)\\
    8&. \quad x+z=2 &(6,7) \\
    9&. \quad \left[\exists_{z}\left[x+z=2\right]\right] &(Exist.Gen.)\\
    10&. \quad\left[ \forall_{y} \left[ x+y=1+y  \right] \implies \exists_{z}\left[x+z=2\right]\right] \\
    11&. \quad \forall_{x}\left[\left[ \forall_{y}\left[x+y=1+y\right]\right]\implies\left[\exists_{z}\left[x+z=2\right]\right]\right] &QED  
\end{align}
We are given strict instruction to split deduction (conclusions) from the right-hand side's line corresponding numbers. If I understand correctly, it follows the rules of Natural Deduction but "baby-feeds" us with many additional comments so that we can start to understand it. We were told to draw lines between equations to show conclusions but I don't know how I could draw lines using the standard LaTeX functions. I'll "draw" conclusions via text:

1. Line 10 is concluded by line 2, because we have declared $x$ and thus, for all $x$ the statement holds
2. Line 9 is concluded by line 3, because, from the implication we assume that if $\forall_{y}\left[x + y = 1 + y\right]$ is true then $\left[\exists_{z}\left[x+z=2\right]\right]$ is also true.
3. Line 8 is concluded by line 4 because we instantiate $y$ to be equal to $1$ and thus, $x+z=2$.

I'll also include an (untidy) image on how to proof structure "should" look:

[image: Updated proof in hand writing]

Apparently, according to my friend, this is wrong. His answer can be found here:
\begin{align}
    1&. \quad \forall_{x}\left[\left[ \forall_{y}\left[x+y=1+y\right]\right]\implies\left[\exists_{z}\left[x+z=2\right]\right]\right]   \\
    2&. \quad x &(declare)\\
    3&. \quad \forall_{y} \left[ x+y=1+y  \right] &(assumed)\\
    4&. \quad x=1 \\
    5&. \quad z = 1  &(choose)\\
    6&. \quad 1 + 1 = 2 &(Peano Ax.)\\
    7&. \quad x+z=2 &(6,4,5) \\
    8&. \quad \left[\exists_{z}\left[x+z=2\right]\right] &(5,7)\\
    9&. \quad\left[ \forall_{y} \left[ x+y=1+y  \right] \implies \exists_{z}\left[x+z=2\right]\right] \\
    10&. \quad \forall_{x}\left[\left[ \forall_{y}\left[x+y=1+y\right]\right]\implies\left[\exists_{z}\left[x+z=2\right]\right]\right] &QED  
\end{align}

An image with his styling can be found here:

[image: Friend's proof in hand writing]

While he definitely gets better marks than me I'm struggling to see how his answer is better than mine.

Thanks so much for your help!

Sorry for the bad formatting. I'm still learning LaTeX. The images were added because of those lines we have to draw and I don't know how to add them while using basic LaTeX. I hope this conforms to the code of conduct. My hand writing is bad, I've been told - sorry!

Comment: "We have to follow a very specific structure in our proofs." In order to do this, you have to state exactly what rules are you allowed to use.

Comment: In your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186404/prove-the-following-for-a-general-binary-operation) you said that the proof system you have to use is **not** Natural Deduction. If so, what else ? Axioms + rules ? If so, we need them.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Thank you for your answer and comment. The hint was a good way of starting me off. Specifically, the idea of Universal instantiation which you linked in the previous post did not make sense to me - but does now. By "We have to follow a very specific structure in our proofs" I rather mean that it would be difficult to ask the question while expecting an answer in the exact structure asked by us. 
As for your second question, it seems that Natural Deduction may be too "fast" of a method for me, personally. It took me a while to understand the logic since it has complex syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch of a proof, to be refined according to the proof system used.

We have to start assuming :

1) $∀y[x+y=1+y]$ --- start of sub-proof

[Instantiating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) it with $y=1$ we get :

2) $x+1=1+1$

Now we need the *laws of arithmetic*, and specifically the law : $1+1=2$, provable from [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic), and [transitivity of equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) to get :

3) $x+1=2$

Now we can conclude by [Existential generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_generalization) with :

4) $∃z[x+z=2]$.

Now we use [Conditional Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof) :

> $∀y[x+y=1+y] \to ∃z[x+z=2]$ --- end of sub-proof.

The result follows by [Universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) :

> > $∀x \ (∀y \ [x+y=1+y] \to ∃z \ [x+z=2])$.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your explanation. I have updated the question with my new attempt. If you don't mind, would you please have a look at my friend and my attempts? You're a legend.